# Xcode 7 error: could not read CFBundleIdentifier from Info.plist (null)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, info.plist

Getting this Error as below:

```
error: could not read CFBundleIdentifier from Info.plist (null)
```

When I opened Xcode 7, it asked to update app to recommended settings, I did so and then ran the project and received the above error.
I haven't changed anything in the project.
What do I need to change here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your `info.plist` from the `Supporting Files` in the Project Navigator on the left, to the Root App folder with the `ViewController.m`'s and `h`'s.

Answer (score 10):

Manesh

You just need to do **update** your all info.plist file.

> Set Bundle identifier, Bundle name again, will work proper.

Answer (score 0):

this simple problem
in xcode open Support Files and move info.plist file to root application folder