# Xcode cannot read info.plist when archiving

Tags: xcode, swift, null

After updating to Xcode 7.3, when I try to archive an app so I can send it to the App Store, I get an error saying:

```
error: could not read CFBundleIdentifier from Info.plist (null)
```

This is annoying, since I've never had this problem before. Is there a fix for this? I added the bundle ID to Info.plist and I still get this issue.

I didn't update recommended settings when updating Xcode, and this error just appeared when I added the bundle ID to my plist file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 7 error: could not read CFBundleIdentifier from Info.plist (null)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563087/xcode-7-error-could-not-read-cfbundleidentifier-from-info-plist-null)

Comment: @aldanux possible, but I didn't update recommended settings. It just made an error after I clicked archive.

Comment: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563087/xcode-7-error-could-not-read-cfbundleidentifier-from-info-plist-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you register the bundle ID on the developer website? If you did, make sure that the bundle ID is identical on Xcode and online.

Comment: glad I could help! :)