# Xcode 7.3: error: could not read CFBundleIdentifier from Info.plist (null) after pods configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, cfbundleidentifier

I've downloaded Telegram's code and I'm playing around trying to add Auth0 with it, so I tried to used pods, replicating the practice code.

After some pain regarding PODS_ROOT, I finally managed to get it going, only to encounter the above error.

And now I'm not sure what to do. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32563087/xcode-7-error-could-not-read-cfbundleidentifier-from-info-plist-null) answer leads me to believe there's an issue with the info.plist file location, but there's too many:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I saw that the `Bundle Identifiers` for the Targets were **blank**, in contrast to the 'base' Telegram app (perhaps something to do with switching from `config` configuration to `Pods-Telegraph`?), which had values in it. So I copied over the `Bundle Identifiers` from the 'base' app like so:

[image]

And promptly ended with this new issue:

`ld: library not found for -lPods-watchkitapp Extension
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

EDIT:

For reference:
[Telegram (iOS version is Objective-C)](http://telegram.org/apps)
[Auth0](https://github.com/auth0/Lock.iOS-OSX/tree/old-sdk)

For replication, I:

- Downloaded necessary files for each project. Telegram is missing some files scattered around the net, and Auth0 requires a (free) account for configuration.
- Created a podfile for Telegram.
- Modified it to resemble Auth0 podfile - Target main app only. If done right, this should replicate the error in question.
- Filled in Bundle Filters (erased upon pod install), based off original values. If done right, this should replicate the UPDATE error in question.

Answer (score 1):

Close your project . Open Again. Clean your project and try to run.

---

And if its not works then Search **info.plist** right click -> Remove reference . And add it again. and try to Build.

[image]

**EDIT :-  After installing pod You need open project from .xcworkspace in place of .xcodeproject .**

[image]

Comment: I see a Telegraph-Info.plist. Is that the one? There'a a lot of info.plists, under every project.

Comment: Find info.plist file of your project . please add screenshot if you didn't identify. (just info.plist)

Comment: I've updated the question. There's new details and new errors.

Comment: @zack_falcon again try to update pod with pod update command.

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't change anything. On a side note, I tried deleting that Pods from Link Binary of the Watchkit target, but I ended up nuking the whole thing even more. This is slowly starting to look hopeless.

Comment: if you are trying to intigrate in demo project then please upload and give me link. so , i can see the problem.

Comment: Very well, here's `Telegram`: https://telegram.org/apps (note: Objective-C) and then there's `Auth0` (also Objective-C): https://github.com/auth0/Lock.iOS-OSX/tree/old-sdk

Comment: I need demo in which you are trying to add

Comment: Those are the demo projects. Telegram is the basis. I've updated the question with details on how to replicate the problem I've encountered.